# SQL Server data pump, migrating many db's into one

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, datapump

So I have a scenario where i have 7+ databases witch I intend to migrate into one database. At one point the plan is to have those 7+ databases handling the metadata but all the sales data will be driven in the new single database.

So I need to keep the metadata on the seven old databases needs to be created,updated & deleted in the new db. ie keep them in one way sync.

I've considered SSIS but have zero experience with that. 
So I just wanted to ask if anyone has ues SSIS with multiple sources ending up in one. The schema in the new database would not be the same as in the old 
database
Does anyone have experience using SSIS doing this ? Would it be easier to create jobs that to this ?

Thanks

Comment: There are many methods for transferring data. If the databases are on a different servers, SSIS might be a good pick. If they're on the same server you can just write T-SQL to do it

Comment: Even if they're on different servers, you can do it with Linked Servers and straight SQL commands, if that's what you're more comfortable with.

Comment: Well Im not talking about one time transfer, but a steady pulse of seven databases insert, updating and deleting data end db